# How to fix this AttributeError

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to access a variable within a function in a class and print it. Whenever I try I keep getting the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'job_ID'.

```
def driver():
    q = my_queue.Queue_()
    for line in df:
        if 'received' in line:
            q.enqueue(line)
            print("Adding job " + q.new_item.job_ID + " to the queue with the timestamp: " + q.new_item.time_stamp + ".")
            print("The prority of the job is: " + q.new_item.job_priority)
            print("The job type is: " + q.new_item.job_type)
        if 'respond' in line:
            q.dequeue()
            print("Completed job " + q.current.job_ID + " in " + str(int(q.time_elapsed)) + " seconds.")
        if 'active' in line:
            q.active_jobs()
            print("Total number of jobs: " + str(len(q.temp)))
            print("Average priority: " + str(q.average))
        if 'modify' in line:
            q.modify(line)
            print("Modified job " + q.current.job_ID)
```

The error is coming from the last print statement in this code.

This is the function within the class that is being used here:

```
def modify(self, x): # need to fix printing bug
        self.current = self.head
        while self.current != None:
            if x[1] in self.current.get_data():
                self.current.data[2] = x[2]
                self.current.data[3] = x[3]
                break
                # print("Modified job " + current.job_ID)
            else:
                # print('The job details cannot be modified.')
                pass
            self.current = self.current.get_next()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit condition for the loop in the `modify` function that you have provided is `self.current == None`.

When you call `modify()` in this last conditional statement:

```
if 'modify' in line:
        q.modify(line) // here
        print("Modified job " + q.current.job_ID)
```

You are making `q.current` evaluate to `None`. Therefore, the reason why you are getting an `AttributeError` is because `q.current` is `None`, which has no such attribute called `job_ID`.

To fix your problem, you must ensure that `q.current` is not `None` before printing `q.current.job_ID`. I can't give you any help beyond this, since I don't know what the purpose of your program is.

Comment: The while loop has the condition `while self.current != None`, so that's why we know that when `modify()` is finished running, `self.current` is `None`. Since you are calling the `modify()` method on the variable `q`, `q.current` will be `None`.

Comment: Since there aren't any lines of code that explicitly make `self.current` evaluate to `None`, it must be the `.get_next()` method that makes `self.current == None`